# How can I replace an if statement with a ternary operator?

Tags: c#, ternary-operator

I am trying to replace the conventional `if` statement with ternary operator, but it does not compile.
First I would like to check if the input is a number, if `true` then assign `Student.ID` to input, if `false`then tell a user to try again.

My code:

```
(Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine().Trim().ToLower())) ? student.ID : Console.WriteLine("id isn't a number, try again");
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You can only replace a if with a Ternary, if you got a assingment operation. You do not show any variable you assign it too. That being said, why would you want to? Ternary operators as harder to debug and read, plus the logic works already.

Comment: I am new to c# and trying to implement my knowledge to see if that works. I know if statement is much more easier but I am just curious how should I change it to a ternary.

Comment: You cant change all if statements to ternary statements. Only if statements that result in assignment to a variable. Ternary statements are syntactic sugar that makes certain if statements easier to write. A ternary equivalent for a simple if statement like this wouldn't reduce the visual complexity of the code at all.

Answer (score 2):

As I read it, you want to output something if the parsing fails. This can not be turned into a ternary.

There is a lot of things that are wrong with your code:

- Tenaries are only for conditional assignments. You do not have a variable you assign anything to.
- you never gave [TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8#System_Int32_TryParse_System_String_System_Int32__) the out parameter, meaning the Compiler can not figure out wich function to even call there
- Both options of a ternary must fit type you are doing assignment too. Console.WriteLine returns void, wich is propably not the same type you will have for Stundent.ID (I asume a integer).

So there are at least 3 reasons this can not compile.

Just keep it at the working if/else block. If you want to try ternaries, do stuff like applying a upper/lower bound for a value. That is what it is designed for. Rarely you use it for initialisation work (if == null, make a new instance. Otherwise give the value).

Edit: I just re-read and noticed that a assignment is not mandatory. It is just the very, very common usecase. And in that case, both results (or their return value) must fit the variable.

Comment: I totally got it. Many tnx

Comment: @bbb A small correction: The assinment does not appear to be nessesary after all. It is just the common usecase. But as student.ID would require a assignment to make sense there and Console.WriteLine will not return anything to assign (not even null), the combination is still a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Christopher answered the question pretty well, so I won't repeat it here.

A workaround for what you're trying to do may be to implement a method that prompts the user for some input and doesn't return until the user enters a string that can be converted to the expected type (and optionally meets some other conditions).

For example:

```
private static int GetIntFromUser(string prompt, Func<int, bool> validator = null)
{
    int result;
    var cursorTop = Console.CursorTop;

    do
    {
        ClearSpecificLineAndWrite(cursorTop, prompt);
    } while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out result) ||
             !(validator?.Invoke(result) ?? true));

    return result;
}

private static void ClearSpecificLineAndWrite(int cursorTop, string message)
{
    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, cursorTop);
    Console.Write(new string(' ', Console.WindowWidth));
    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, cursorTop);
    Console.Write(message);
}
```

Now we can call this method in our main program and not worry about validation - our main code is much cleaner.

For example, say a student number must be 5 digits long, we could do something like:

```
int studentId = GetIntFromUser("Enter a 5-digit student id: ", x => x > 9999 && x < 100000);
```